# Handling missing values and wrong values in pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, nan

I'm trying to handle missing values in my dataset. 
I'm using pandas in Python 3.
I have a column 'name' that should only contain names of people, but it also contains random numbers. How can I remove them or change them to NaN, so later on I can drop them or fill them with new names. 
This is how I handled the first missing values:

```
df_test["name"] = df_test['name'].astype(str)
df_test['name'].replace('-inf', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_test['name'].replace('0', np.nan, inplace=True)
df_test
```

Output:

```
     name    
1    NaN         
2    NaN     
3    29014
...
10   21893
11   Amber Rose
```

So the first two values were '-inf' and '0' I replaced them with NaN but how can I replace random numbers in a string column? Do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the numbers with `NaN` like below:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [np.NaN, np.NaN, '29014', '21893', 'Amber Rose']
})
```

---

```
df_test['name'] = np.where(
    pd.to_numeric(df_test['name'], errors='coerce').isnull()==False,
    np.NaN,
    df_test['name']
)
```

---

```
df_test
    name
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   Amber Rose
```